# Does fondling during ghusl invalidate ghusl?

Tags: halal-haram, taharah, ghusl

I was meaning to ask that during my ghusl, i used my hand to clean my private parts.  but what i thought was that i had to put my fingers in deep to clean up but i was wrong. Do i have to do ghusl again because i did feel aroused and i was kind of fondling with it before. i did wash it again after that happened in my ghusl because i felt like i wasn’t clean after a while Please let me know.

Comment: I think your inquiry is already covered in [Does masturbating while bathing-ghusl invalidate the bath?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61591/does-masturbating-while-bathing-ghusl-invalidate-the-bath)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What things require performing ghusl?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/what-things-require-performing-ghusl)

Answer (score 0):

No need to do ghusl again. If you touched you private part after wudu your wudu is broken and you have to do wudu again. In the circumstances there is no need to do ghusl again.